# In Windows, what's the difference between enumerating logged on users vs sessions?

Tags: windows, penetration-test, powershell

I'm reading over [`PowerView.ps1`](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/Recon/PowerView.ps1), part of [PowerSploit](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit), and I'm wondering: what's the difference between sessions and logged on users? [`Get-NetLoggedon`](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/7b49e54eecbece602fe5186d1d7d7242aa001453/Recon/PowerView.ps1#L8079) (which uses the [`NetWkstaUserEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370669(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API call, and requires local admin rights) always seems to return more results than [`Get-NetSession`](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/7b49e54eecbece602fe5186d1d7d7242aa001453/Recon/PowerView.ps1#L8173) (which uses the [`NetSessionEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525382(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API call). That's the opposite of what I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logged on user may have multiple sessions on a network connection - akin to the idea of threads in an application possibly.

In addition, sessions will likely refresh a lot more often than login events. This is especially true of more modern authentication and authorisation methods such as OAuth.